# Technology to transfer data with external system

Tags: java, interface, communication, message-queue

We have an interface with an external system in which we get flat files from them and process those files. At present we run a job a few times a day that checks if the file is at the ftp location and then processes if it exists.
I recently read that it is a bad idea to make use of file systems as a message broker which is why I am putting in this question. Can someone clarify if a situation like this one is a right fitment for the use of some other tool and if so which one?
Ours is a java based application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question you should ask is "is it working?".

If the answer to that is yes, then you should be circumspect about change just because you read it was a bad idea. I've read that chocolate may be bad for you but I'm not giving it up :-)

There *are* potential problems that you can run into, such as files being deleted without your knowledge, or trying to process files that are only half-transferred (though there are ways to mitigate both of those, such as permissions in the former case, or the use of sentinel files or content checking in the latter case).

Myself, I would prefer a message queueing system such as IBM's MQ or JMS (since that's what they're built for, and they do make life a little easier) but, as per the second paragraph above, only if either:

- problems appear or become evident with the current solution; or
- you have some spare time and money lying around for unnecessary rework.

The last bullet needs expansion. While the work may be unnecessary (in terms of fixing a non-existent problem), that doesn't necessarily make it useless, especially if it can improve performance or security, or reduce the maintenance effort.

Comment: I completely agree.  Polling for "flag files" is a perfectly appropriate thing to do in circumstances like this.  There's *nothing* necessarily wrong with it.

Comment: Doesn't this amount to a file system being used as a message broker, which essentially is akin to writing your own messaging system(Derek C. Ashmore; J2EE Architect's handbook)?. Although the current solution works I just wanted to be know what would be the best approach that I could use in the future for implementing these.

Comment: @sarego, no, not quite, it does not involve "writing your own message broker". What I'm trying to get across is that, while you probably shouldn't write a filesystem-based message queueing system from scratch, don't throw away one that's _already there_ just because you think it _may_ be less than optimal. The best approach, if you're starting from scratch, is to use an already-built-and-very-well-tested message queueing product like MQ.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a database to synchronize your files. Have a database that points to the file locations. Put an entry into the database only when the files have been fully transferred. This would ensure that you are picking up completed files. You can poll the database to check if new entries are present instead of polling the file system. A very easy simple set up for a polling mechanism. If you would like to be told when a new file appears on the folder, then you would need to go in for a Message Queue.